# How to combine header and navigation bar

Tags: html, css

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  color: #6600ff;
  text-align: center;
}

#ul {
  background-color: #6600ff;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*oznake v seznamu*/
  margin: 0;
  /*to remove browser default settings*/
  padding: 0;
  /*to remove browser default settings*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /* ce bi b boxsu bilo prevec vsebine*/
  background-color: #1a1aff;
  /*barva navigacije*/
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  /*kot block elements naredi celotno areo clickable-ne samo tekst*/
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*skrijes podcrtano besedilo*/
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #000033;
  /*barva ozadja ko se postavimo z misko*/
}
```

```html
<pre>
    <div class="sticky">
      
       <h1 id="h1">my web page </h1>
        
       <ul id="ul">
        <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
        <li><a href="ponudba.html">Ponudba</a></li>
        <li><a href="anketa.html">Anketa</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://estudij.um.si" target="_blank">Vaje</a></li>
       </ul>
      
    </div>
    </pre>
```

Now I need to combine h1 and navigation bar so there won't be space in the middle. I tried combining them with different classes, but the result is still the same, space remains.

My output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZATOX.jpg

How I need it to be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q85D6.jpg

Comment: Have you checked margin and padding? Usually they are releveant when it comes to spaces.

Comment: Please provide the HTML code

Comment: why are you using `pre` tag? it's causing half the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here are the pre tags, you need to delete those and then set a margin: 0 for the h1

```
#h1{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffcc00;
    color: #6600ff;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0; /*Added*/
}
```

let me know if that helps.

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#h1 {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  color: #6600ff;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  /*Added*/
}

#ul {
  background-color: #6600ff;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  /*oznake v seznamu*/
  margin: 0;
  /*to remove browser default settings*/
  padding: 0;
  /*to remove browser default settings*/
  overflow: hidden;
  /* ce bi b boxsu bilo prevec vsebine*/
  background-color: #1a1aff;
  /*barva navigacije*/
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  /*kot block elements naredi celotno areo clickable-ne samo tekst*/
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*skrijes podcrtano besedilo*/
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #000033;
  /*barva ozadja ko se postavimo z misko*/
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">

  <h1 id="h1">my web page </h1>

  <ul id="ul">
    <li><a href="index.html">Domov</a></li>
    <li><a href="ponudba.html">Ponudba</a></li>
    <li><a href="anketa.html">Anketa</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://estudij.um.si" target="_blank">Vaje</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```